# Как в JS динамически создать объект нужного Класса, если имя Класса указано в переменной?

Tags: javascript, классы, объекты, google-apps-script

```
class Class1 { }
class Class2 { }
class Class3 { }

className = 'Class1';

// Как динамически создать объект нужного Класса, если имя Класса указано в переменной className?
```

Comment: Сложить их в объект. Но в целом это обычно не нужно и скорее всего означает ошибку проектирования

Comment: Суть вопроса неясна. Как и наличие классов в этом языке. Но это уже риторика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать это динамически через eval, который выполняет код из строки

```js
class Class1 { }
class Class2 { }
class Class3 { }

const className = 'Class1';

console.log(eval(`new ${className}()`) instanceof Class1);
```

Но будет проще, если классы находятся в переменной. Например вот так

```js
const classList = {
    'Class1': class {},
    'Class2': class {},
    'Class3': class {},
};

const className = 'Class1';

console.log(new classList[className]() instanceof classList.Class1);
```